# Is there a way to enable the macro code upon clicking on the save icon or File -> save in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to validate some form in excel with vb code and when the user clicks on save icon, the vb code is not validating and allowing to save the form without required fields. Also when the user tries to save the file via the `File -> Save` option, the form validation is not working.

**For example:** Prompting the user to fill the required fields.

Any suggestions for this problem?

It is working upon keyboard `Ctrl + S` option where I specified the settings in the Developer -> Macros options, but not working with the save icon or `File-> Save` option.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you are using. This helps us help you!

Comment: You can use the [before save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave) event.

Comment: Your macro hotkey is hijacking the Ctrl+S default hotkey for "save"; you'll want to remove that hotkey and invoke the macro from the `BeforeSave` event handler of the `ThisWorkbook` module, assuming the workbook being edited is the same workbook that contains the VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You want an *event handler* for the `BeforeSave` event of the `Workbook` object:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave

Comment: I am now facing issues with clearing the form to upload in a website so that users can download the empty form. Since I implemented the BeforeSave event, it is not allowing me to clear the form. Any suggestions for this problem?